# jQuery slider is acting odd in Chrome (+ other issues)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, slider

Currently working on a website with a slider that is acting up in Chrome and it's becoming a problem.

http://firedogpr.com/index.php -  the top banner with 5 slides, using jquery blend tends to not load some images by random and speeds up or stops working when on the site for about 5-10 minutes. I have another site using a different slider and the same issue occurs, so it may not just be the plugin. I have modelled it after the slider on http://www.snowdenindustries.com/ and in fact used the same js file and div tags, although that works just fine.

Minimal issues in Firefox, but usually when changing tabs.

Any ideas?

Working on Chrome 17.0.963.46 on Mac OSX

Update: Will not work at all on Chrome, Firefox or IE in Windows. My partner's Mac laptop is experiencing the same issue across his browsers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/03/getting-smoother-animated-web-content.html):

> Unfortunately, setTimeout and setInterval don’t take into
>   consideration whether the destination element, or even the tab that
>   contains it, is actually visible. So, pages with high-frequency timers
>   will consume CPU resources even if the tab is in the background. On
>   laptops, netbooks, and mobile devices of all kinds, reducing CPU
>   consumption is essential in order to prolong battery life.
>   Additionally, excess CPU consumption by background tabs reduces the
>   smoothness of animations on the foreground tab. ...
>
> In the forthcoming Chrome 11 release, we plan to reduce CPU
>   consumption even for pages that are using setTimeout and setInterval.
>   For background tabs, we intend to run each independent timer no more
>   than once per second. This change has already been implemented in the
>   Chrome dev channel and canary builds. While there may be some
>   compatibility impact for web pages, we believe that improving the user
>   experience for the foreground tab, and increasing battery life, are
>   problems needing to be addressed.

Comment: Thank you for the info, even though it gives some idea to what may be the problem, unfortunately it still doesn't solve the issue. Checking windows now and it doesn't work at all across all three major browsers.